# Not able to run commands on Hbase shell

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I keep getting `INFO ipc.HBaseRPC: Problem connecting to server: /129.10.193.117:49176` when I try to create or disable tables in Hbase. I have googled this error and found couple of answers. All of them say something like **"Default installation added a line in /etc/hosts which linked to machine hostname with the IP 127.0.1.1."**

Here is my etc/host file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Also my conf/regionservers is pointing to localhost. Does anyone know how to fix this ? After shutting down hbase & Hadoop and then restarting my system, I do not get this error. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hadoop configurations also pointing to localhost ?

Comment: Where should I check this ? I am running both hadoop and hbase on standalone mode.

Comment: in core-site.xml in hadoop conf

Comment: But I am running hadoop in standalone mode.